# Run GUI apps inside fakechroot debootstrap

Tags: gnome, chroot, debootstrap

I'm following the tutorial on https://github.com/dex4er/fakechroot.

I'm trying to install and run some apps keeping them isolated on an unprivileged user, without root. They are proprietary software distributed as .deb, so normally I'd need to go root to install them, but I don't wanna install them on the general system.

The easiest solution would be install them on a VM, but I'm trying to do it first with fakechroot to save RAM.

CLI apps work fine, as hello on the tutorial. But GUI apps fail with

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:1
$ fakechroot fakeroot chroot /home/restricted/chroot firefox
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

Error: cannot open display: :1
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. How can I authorize it to use the display?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: hello, version 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I wasn't an issue with fakechroot debootstrap, but with the restricted account. Even normal apps didn't execute.

I had to run `xhost + local:` on my main account under wich GUI is running, then it worked.

We just must make sure to know that there's some security risks when running a GUI app from another account.

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameter `--display=:0.0`

Comment: Thanks. My mistake, I didn't verify. Indeed, $DISPLAY is :1 I'll fix the question.